# authentication Oauth 2.0 Google Calendar

Tags: java, api, oauth

I have a problem when i try to authenticate with my google account, to insert/get events from my calendar on google

i use this code:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Calendars;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Calendars.Insert;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessProtectedResource.Method;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class connect{

        //connessione Google for unauthorized user for a limited usage
                /*JsonHttpRequestInitializer initializer = new GoogleKeyInitializer("AIzaSyCuWqLpR9G4QhfJ1QMbqh3pa0vul6sd8yQ");
                Plus plus = Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new GenericUrl())
                    .setApplicationName("Progetto SITI")
                    .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(initializer)
                    .build();*/
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        // The clientId and clientSecret are copied from the API Access tab on
        // the Google APIs Console
        String clientId = "MYCLIENTID";
        String clientSecret = " MYSECRETID ";

        // Or your redirect URL for web based applications.
        String redirectUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarID}";
        String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

        // Step 1: Authorization-->
        String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, scope)
            .build();

        // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
        System.out.println("Navigate the link on your browser:");
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

        // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
        System.out.println("What's your authorization code?");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = in.readLine();
        // EndStep 1 <--

        // Step 2: Change-->
        AccessTokenResponse authResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();
        System.out.println("Token d'accesso: "+authResponse.accessToken);
        if(scope == "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
        System.out.println("Scope di lettura e scrittura usato :"+scope);
        else
            System.out.println("Scope di sola lettura usato :"+scope);
        // End Step 2 <--

        GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                authResponse.accessToken, httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
                authResponse.refreshToken);
        System.out.println("Client ID: "+accessProtectedResource.getClientId());
        System.out.println("Secret ID: "+accessProtectedResource.getClientSecret());
        System.out.println("Authentication Url: "+accessProtectedResource.getAuthorizationServerUrl());

        Calendar prova = new Calendar(httpTransport, jsonFactory);
        Calendar cale = new Calendar(httpTransport, jsonFactory);
        com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar cal = new com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar();
        cal.setSummary("My test Calendar");
        cal.setDescription("This calendar was created with the API v3.");
        cal.setTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam");
        cal.setLocation("Amsterdam");
        cal.setId("4");
        String summary = cal.getSummary();
        System.out.println(summary);
        prova.calendars().insert(cal);
        prova.calendars().delete("Caldario prova");
        //Calendar calendarService = null;
        //Calendars calendarList = cale.calendars();
        //Insert insert = calendarList.insert(cal);
        //cal = insert.execute();
        System.out.println("Job Done");
      }
}
```

i don't know why every time i run this code my browser report me this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

when i copy the link to the browser i accept the authorization for my project, but after the error appaer

someone can help me?
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to just use this as a command-line sample, you need to change the:

```
String redirectUrl =  "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarID}";
```

to

```
String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
```

This indicates that you're using [OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) (out of band).  Google will give you the authorization code in your browser which you can copy/paste into your app.